# Integrating SendBird with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, sendbird

in the index.html I added the

```
<div id="sb_widget"></div>
and

<script src="web-widget/SendBird.min.js"></script>
<script src="web-widget/build/widget.SendBird.js"></script>
<script>
  sbWidget.start(Appid);
</script>
```

it works fine but I need to implement it in my react app
my scripts are still in index.html but I put the div(`<div id="sb_widget"></div>`) in my app.js
but nothing happened it's not working anymore
so how could I implement it in a reactjs app ??